# How to parse ClinicalDocument response using fhir API

Tags: java, hl7-fhir

I got response as a <clinicalDocument ....> response, i have to parse this xml response using fhier api. not able to find the api which can parse this response.
If someone knows please help me out for the same. Thanks a lot in advance.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you're receiving an HL7 CDA clinical document and you're wanting to turn it into FHIR.  *IF* the CDA is compliant with the C-CDA (Consolidated CDA) specification, you can look at the transformation guidance provided in the C-CDA on FHIR implementation guide (http://hl7.org/fhir/us/ccda/).  Otherwise, there's no specific guidance on how to convert - because CDA documents can be populated so many different ways.  You'll have to do the mapping yourself based on the design of your specific document.